# Error: Compile Error: DML requires SObject or SObject list type: Map<Account,Decimal> at line 31 column 11

Tags: apex, trigger

in 5 related case records if status__c pilklist is yes and checkbox is true ,then in its parent account ,the custom field no_of_closed_status_in_case__c should get updated as 5 .for this above trigger i am trying it using lists and maps but it is throughing error as

```
Error: Compile Error: DML requires SObject or SObject list type: Map<Account,Decimal> at line 31 column 11
```

--

```
trigger statupdtrecbulk on Case (before insert) {


list<id> accslst = new list<id>();
 for(case cs: trigger.new)
   {
       if(cs.status__c=='yes'&& cs.check_box__c==True)
       accslst.add(cs.id);

   }
      list<account> acc = new list<account>();
acc = [select id,no_of_closed_status_in_case__c,(select id,check_box__c,accountid from cases) from account where id in :accslst];

      map<account,decimal> alst = new map<account,decimal>();
   for(account ac1l : acc)
   {
     if(ac1l.no_of_closed_status_in_case__c == NULL)
         {
        ac1l.no_of_closed_status_in_case__c = 0;
        ac1l.no_of_closed_status_in_case__c=ac1l.no_of_closed_status_in_case__c+1;
          alst.put(ac1l,ac1l.no_of_closed_status_in_case__c);
         } 
         else
         {
          ac1l.no_of_closed_status_in_case__c=ac1l.no_of_closed_status_in_case__c+1;
          alst.put(ac1l,ac1l.no_of_closed_status_in_case__c);
      } 

   } 
      update alst;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Krishna,

You cannot update a map like that. Sets are not available for DML.

If you want to optimize, try changing your code to this:

```
list<id> accslst = new list<id>();
 for(case cs: trigger.new)
   {
       if(cs.status__c=='yes'&& cs.check_box__c==True)
       accslst.add(cs.id);

   }
      list<account> acc = new list<account>();
acc = [select id,no_of_closed_status_in_case__c,(select id,check_box__c,accountid from cases) from account where id in :accslst];

   for(account ac1l : acc)
   {
     if(ac1l.no_of_closed_status_in_case__c == NULL)
         {
        ac1l.no_of_closed_status_in_case__c = 1;
         } 
         else
         {
          ac1l.no_of_closed_status_in_case__c += 1;
          } 

   } 
      update acc;
```

Comment: still it is throwing the error

Comment: Error: Compile Error: DML requires SObject or SObject list type: Set<Account> at line 31 column 11

Comment: Can I see how your code looks now?

Comment: I edited the answer to include some a better way

Comment: You can't update `Set<SObject>`. You also added a query in a for loop.

Comment: There is no query in a for/loop in my edited code or her original one. Edited my answer to reflect the lack of Edit on Sets.

Comment: Ah it looks like there is one just b/c the indentation is so inconsistent. Makes it kind of hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against using `SObject` records as map keys. Usually using their `Id` is much simpler and more stable. Regardless, the error describes exactly what the problem is, you can only update two data structures: `SObject` or `List<SObject>`. Here you are using a collection, so you need the latter:

```
List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>(alst.keySet());
update accounts;
```